# Split text into sentences using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regex and trying to split text into sentences.

Here is my text

*"Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't."*

And my regex and code

```
result = re.match(r"(.*\.{1}\s{1})[A-Z].*",line)
```

result.group(1) gives me

*"Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true..."*

I want it to just give me a sentence till the first occurrence of a ".".
I understand that this is a greedy match but could not figure out how to achieve this and so looking of help.

Note: I found many regex online that split text into sentences, but wanted to do it myself. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why not just `.*?\.`? The `?` after `.*` makes it lazy. Note that it seems you want to spit it into `Mr.`, ` Smith bought cheapsite.`, `com for 1.`, etc.

Comment: *wanted to do it myself* - then why asking? Do you realize that the first `.` is after an abbreviation `Mr`?

Comment: I want to make sure there is only one "." followed by a space and then an upper case char.

Comment: In that case, use `.*?\. [A-Z]`

Comment: I will work on the Mr. Dr. Mrs. etc after I figure this out.

Comment: @Druzion it works!!! Can you tell me what is wrong with my approach

Comment: Look at my answer, it gives a slightly safer one. And yes, give me 2 mins

Comment: If you looking for text into sentences. You can use `nltk` package and it have tokenize options for sentences.

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html here is the link.

Comment: @RahulKP I actually wanted to do it using regex, just to learn.

Comment: Cool. Just mentioned the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following RegEx:

```
.*?\.(?= [A-Z]|$)
```

`.*?` will select optional data, however it is lazy (it will select up to the first `.`)

The `(?=)` is a **Positive Lookahead**. It will check the data exists, but not capture it, so you will not end up with `My first sentence. M`, like the RegEx below. It will check for either a space followed by an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`), or (`|`) the end of the string (`$`)

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/tW3cC9/1)</kbd>

---

### Safest Regex (deals with `Mr.` and `Mrs.`)

To stop the `Mr.` from messing up the RegEx, you can add a **Negative Lookbehind** to the RegEx:

```
.*?(?<!Mr|Mrs)\.(?= [A-Z]|$)
```

The Negative Lookbehind will look backwards to check if there is a `Mr` or `Mrs` before the dot. If there is, the match will fail (this will not be the end of a sentence).

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/lL1kG5/1)</kbd>

---

You could use `.*?\. [A-Z]`, however that will not catch the last sentence in the string. It will also match the space and letter after the sentence, i.e. `My first sentence. M`

The main problem with your RegEx was that the very first `.*` was not lazy, it should have been `.*?`, however the capture groups were also a little weird too.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me correct my regex to match the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks!! That taught me a lot.

Comment: @MukundGandlur Hey. Is there a way to also include "!" and "?" in the check? My attempts at doing this failed miserably and I need it for a program I'm making.

Comment: @user9123 Yes, special characters can be included in a regex by escaping them with a `\ `, so `Mr\?` would match the text "`Mr?`"